# email in truecrypt

Tags: macos, email, truecrypt

Is there some way to drag my Mac email program and files into my truecrypt partition
so that I open it after opening truecrypt?

Comment: You do realize that your emails are still stored either with your email service provider or in your user directory, so anyone with physical access to your machine still can read your email?

Comment: Which email program? Apple Mail?

Answer (score 0):

You could create symbolic links to the items that you want to secure, but never having done that I don't know if there are any unforeseen consequences of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

**Store Mail folders and prefs on a secure disk image**

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030415132128751